# passport-remember-me functionality not working in my sails js application

Tags: sails.js, remember-me

I’m struggling with passport-remember-me functionality in my app since a few days but didn’t find a way to make it a successful implementation. I’ve followed every instructions given in the documentation and followed various examples given by Jared Hanson. However, it doesn’t work.

The code seems to be right, as it sets the cookie when a user logs in to my application. It also consumes the token correctly when session  gets expired and re-issues a new token. After reissuance of token, it updates the cookie with that token. So everything seems correct though when session gets expired, the user gets redirected to the login page.

Can anybody please give some pointers on what could be the issue ? Do I need to check cookie in my sessionAuth.js where I’m checking whether the user is authenticated. The code is as below.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  // User is allowed, proceed to the next policy,
  // or if this is the last policy, the controller
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

    return next();
  }
  console.log(" not authenticated in ");
  // User is not allowed
  // (default res.forbidden() behavior can be overridden in `config/403.js`)
  req.flash('message', 'The user session has expired. Please login!')
   return res.redirect('/login');
};
```